# IndexError の解消法

Tags: python, python2

何処かの `int` 型が抜けていると思われるのですが...

**エラーメッセージ**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ymtk/Desktop/pyaudio/mfcc.py", line 109, in <module>
    mfcc = MFCC(stf.SPEC.shape[1] * 2, stf.frequency)
  File "/Users/ymtk/Desktop/pyaudio/mfcc.py", line 29, in __init__
    self.filterbank, self.fcenters = self.melFilterBank()
  File "/Users/ymtk/Desktop/pyaudio/mfcc.py", line 62, in melFilterBank
    filterbank[c, i] = (i - indexstart[c]) * increment
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

**ソースコード**

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8

import numpy
import scipy.fftpack
import scipy.interpolate
import scipy.linalg
import sys

from stf import STF

class MFCC:
    '''
    MFCC computation from spectrum information

    Reference
    ---------
     - http://aidiary.hatenablog.com/entry/20120225/1330179868
    '''

    def __init__(self, nfft, frequency, dimension = 16, channels = 20):
        self.nfft = nfft
        self.frequency = frequency
        self.dimension = dimension
        self.channels = channels

        self.fscale = \
            numpy.fft.fftfreq(self.nfft, d = 1.0 / self.frequency)[: self.nfft / 2]
        self.filterbank, self.fcenters = self.melFilterBank()

    def hz2mel(self, f):
        return 1127.01048 * numpy.log(f / 700.0 + 1.0)

    def mel2hz(self, m):
        return 700.0 * (numpy.exp(m / 1127.01048) - 1.0)

    def melFilterBank(self):
        # サンプリング周波数の半分(ナイキスト周波数)までを対象とする
        fmax = self.frequency / 2
        melmax = self.hz2mel(fmax)

        # 周波数に合わせて、サンプル数の半分の標本数で計算する
        nmax = self.nfft / 2
        df = self.frequency / self.nfft

        # フィルタごとの中心となるメル尺度を計算する
        dmel = melmax / (self.channels + 1)
        melcenters = numpy.arange(1, self.channels + 1) * dmel
        fcenters = self.mel2hz(melcenters)

        # それぞれの標本が対象とする周波数の範囲を計算する
        indexcenter = numpy.round(fcenters / df)
        indexstart = numpy.hstack(([0], indexcenter[0: self.channels - 1]))
        indexstop = numpy.hstack((indexcenter[1: self.channels], [nmax]))

        # フィルタごとにindexstartを始点、indexcenterを頂点、
        # indexstopを終点とする三角形のグラフを描くように計算する
        filterbank = numpy.zeros((self.channels, nmax))
        for c in numpy.arange(0, self.channels):
            increment = 1.0 / (indexcenter[c] - indexstart[c])
            for i in numpy.arange(indexstart[c], indexcenter[c]):
                filterbank[c, i] = (i - indexstart[c]) * increment
            decrement = 1.0 / (indexstop[c] - indexcenter[c])
            for i in numpy.arange(indexcenter[c], indexstop[c]):
                filterbank[c, i] = 1.0 - ((i - indexcenter[c]) * decrement)
            filterbank[c] /= (indexstop[c] - indexstart[c]) / 2

        return filterbank, fcenters

    def mfcc(self, spectrum):
        # スペクトル包絡として負の値が与えられた場合は、0として扱う
        spectrum = numpy.maximum(numpy.zeros(spectrum.shape), spectrum)
        # スペクトル包絡とメルフィルタバンクの積の対数を取る
        mspectrum = numpy.log10(numpy.dot(spectrum, self.filterbank.transpose()))
        # scipyを用いて離散コサイン変換をする
        return scipy.fftpack.dct(mspectrum, norm='ortho')[:self.dimension]

    def delta(self, mfcc):
        # データの開始部と終了部は同じデータが続いているものとする
        mfcc = numpy.concatenate([[mfcc[0]], mfcc, [mfcc[-1]]])

        delta = None
        for i in xrange(1, mfcc.shape[0] - 1):
            # 前後のフレームの差を2で割ったものを動的変化量とする
            slope = (mfcc[i + 1] - mfcc[i - 1]) / 2
            if delta is None:
                delta = slope
            else:
                delta = numpy.vstack([delta, slope])

        return delta

    def imfcc(self, mfcc):
        # MFCCの削られた部分に0を代入した上で、逆離散コサイン変換をする
        mfcc = numpy.hstack([mfcc, [0] * (self.channels - self.dimension)])
        mspectrum = scipy.fftpack.idct(mfcc, norm='ortho')
        # 得られた離散的な値をスプライン補間によって連続的にする
        tck = scipy.interpolate.splrep(self.fcenters, numpy.power(10, mspectrum))
        return scipy.interpolate.splev(self.fscale, tck)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print 'Usage: %s <ymtkyo.stf>' % sys.argv[0]
        # sys.exit()

    stf = STF()
    stf.loadfile("/Users/ymtk/Desktop/pyaudio/ymtkyo.stf")

    mfcc = MFCC(stf.SPEC.shape[1] * 2, stf.frequency)
    res = mfcc.mfcc(stf.SPEC[stf.SPEC.shape[0] / 5])
    spec = mfcc.imfcc(res)

    print res

    import pylab

    pylab.subplot(211)
    pylab.plot(stf.SPEC[stf.SPEC.shape[0] / 5])
    pylab.ylim(0, 1.2)
    pylab.subplot(212)
    pylab.plot(spec)
    pylab.ylim(0, 1.2)
    pylab.show()
```

Comment: `indexcenter` が `float64` 型になっている事が原因です。`indexstart`, `indexstop` と同様に `int64` 型に変換しておくと良いかと。`indexcenter = numpy.round(fcenters / df).astype(numpy.int64)`

Comment: ありがとうございます。エラーが解消されて結果が出ました

Answer (score 1):

`indexcenter` が `float64` 型になっている事が原因です。

`indexstart`, `indexstop` と同様に `int64` 型に変換しておくと良いかと。

```
indexcenter = numpy.round(fcenters / df).astype(numpy.int64)
```

---

*この投稿は [@metropolis さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/62041/indexerror-%e3%81%ae%e8%a7%a3%e6%b6%88%e6%b3%95#comment67679_62041) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*